# Setting class name dynamically in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, lwc-dom

I want to add class to a div dynamically,something like this :

```
<div class={getShowHideClassesInvoicesAndPayments} >
#!----content-#
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
getShowHideClassesInvoicesAndPayments(){
    return this._showInvoicesAndPayments? "slds-show":"slds-hide";
}
```

Error:

```
AuraError {component: '', componentStack: '[runtime_online_sales:onlineSalesHomePage]', action: null, name: 'InvalidCharacterError', message: " 
[Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The t…space characters, which are not valid in tokens.]", …}
```

Looks like is takes '{' in the dom to add the class, not sure why its doing that

Comment: Getter as casper mentioned is a right solution, but if you need to access method directly in class attribute, might need to access it as a function: `class={getShowHideClassesInvoicesAndPayments()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter syntax needs fixing:

```
<div class={contentVisibilityClass} >
#!----content-#
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
get contentVisibilityClass(){
    return this._showInvoicesAndPayments? "slds-show":"slds-hide";
}
```

The `get` keyword needs to be used to denote a getter, which will the getter is invoked at the correct time.